# Iterative filter function that modifies tree like structure

Tags: algorithm, rust, tree, borrow-checker

I have a structure like

```
struct Node {
    pub id: String,
    pub dis: String,
    pub parent: Option<NodeRefNodeRefWeak>,
    pub children: Vec<NodeRef>,
}

pub type NodeRef = Rc<RefCell<Node>>;
pub type NodeRefNodeRefWeak = Weak<RefCell<Node>>;
```

I also have a start of a function that can iterate this structure to
pull out a match on a node id but it has issues.

What I would like is for this function to return the parent node of the whole tree with ONLY the branches that have a match somewhere on the branch.
Children past the search node can be removed.
Ie a function that filters all other nodes out of the tree.

For example with my rust playground link I would like it to return

> level0_node_@1 (level0_node_@1)
>
> ```
> level1_node_4 (level1_node_4)
>
>     level2_node_4_3 (level2_node_4_3)
>
>         level3_node_4_3_2 (level3_node_4_3_2)
> ```

However, using the recursive approach as below causes real issue with already borrowed errors when trying to remove branches etc.
Is there a way to achieve this filter function?

I have a test in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11ac285aef77936f5ea03bd1b8227e5a).

```
fn tree_filter_node_objects<F>(node: &NodeRef, f: F) -> Vec<NodeRef>
    where F: Fn(&str) -> bool + Copy { 

    let mut filtered_nodes: Vec<NodeRef> = vec![];

    let mut borrow = node.borrow_mut();

    if f(&borrow.id) {
        filtered_nodes.push(node.clone());
    }

    for n in borrow.children.iter() {
        let children_filtered = tree_filter_node_objects(n, f);
        for c in children_filtered.iter() {
            filtered_nodes.push(c.clone());
        }
    }

    filtered_nodes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used this iterative approach.

```
pub fn tree_filter_node_dfs<F>(root: &NodeRef, f: F) -> Vec<NodeRef>
    where F: Fn(&BmosHaystackObject) -> bool + Copy { 

    let mut filtered_nodes: Vec<NodeRef> = vec![];
    let mut cur_node: Option<NodeRef> = Some(root.clone());
    let mut last_visited_child: Option<NodeRef> = None;
    let mut next_child: Option<NodeRef>;
    let mut run_visit: bool = true;

    while cur_node.is_some() {

        if run_visit {
            
            let n = cur_node.as_ref().unwrap();

            if f(&n.borrow().object) {
        
            }
        }

        if last_visited_child.is_none() {
            let children = cur_node.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().children.clone();
            if children.len() > 0 {
                next_child = Some(children[0].clone());
            }
            else {
                next_child = None;
            }
        }
        else {
            next_child = tree_filter_node_get_next_sibling(last_visited_child.as_ref().unwrap());
        }

        if next_child.is_some() {
            last_visited_child = None;
            cur_node = next_child;
            run_visit = true;
        }
        else {
            last_visited_child = cur_node;
            cur_node = tree_node_parent_node(&last_visited_child.clone().unwrap().clone());
            run_visit = false;

        }
    }

    filtered_nodes
}
```